# Antecedents of prepositions and adverbs

Tags: prepositions, adverbs, anaphora

It seems that some prepositions and clausal adverbs have antecedents while others do not – for example *because* and *therefore* require antecedents, while *in* and *clearly* do not. I was wondering whether this property has a name, and where I could find discussion of how the antecedents are selected.

Comment: _Antecedent_ already has a meaning dealing with coreference of nouns and pronouns; although the etymology is reasonable, it's probly not the right word for what you're asking about. _Because_ and _therefore_ have reference to some portion of the (normally previous) discourse which occasions their use; in this case it's via a causal connection (in both directions with these two words). Though one might want to say that _in the cellar on the shelf_ has reference to whatever NP in the discourse is said to be located there.

Comment: Perhaps the term you are looking for is _predicate_ instead of _antecedent_. In this regard, the preposition _in_ can in fact be viewed as a predicate taking two arguments in a sentence like _The beer is in the fridge_: IN (THE BEER, THE FRIDGE). This is similar to subordinators like _because_, which arguably take two arguments, the matrix clause and the subordinate clause.

Comment: Yes, perhaps it’s more about valency. *Therefore* sometimes seems to have two arguments (*he’d had his fill of wine and was therefore careless in his speech*) and sometimes three (*he detests being told what to do; when he received the order, therefore, he was furious*). But perhaps it always has three arguments and it's just that sometimes the third one (the explanation) can be left unstated when it’s obvious.

Comment: That seems to explain why I can’t say *because she was there therefore I spoke to her*, despite the parallel with *if she’s there then I’ll speak to her*, and why I can’t say *when he heard the news he was therefore in a good mood* (or not without supplying the third argument somewhere else), even though I can say *when he had heard the news and was therefore in a good mood...*.

Comment: @rchivers “When he heard the news, he was therefore in a good mood” sounds perfectly fine to me; works in reverse too. Because of ‘this’ (whatever in the preceding text _therefore_ refers back to), he was in a good mood at the point in time when he heard the news. What definitely _is_ impossible is “When he heard the news, therefore he was in a good mood”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I agree - that's what I meant by "not without supplying the third argument somewhere else", but I probably wasn't very clear. *He heard the good news* can't be the antecedent/p/a (should that be the *only* one?) in *when he heard the news he was therefore in a good mood*, even though it can be in *he had heard the news and was therefore in a good mood*. I guess another possibility is that the antecedent/p/a can't be located inside a prepositional phrase, unless the *therefore* is also inside that phrase, as in *when he had heard the news and was therefore in a good mood...*.

Answer (score 1):

Conjunctions like "because" and "which" that are found at the beginning of a dependent clause are often referred to as "subordinating conjunctions" to distinguish them from conjunctions like "and" or "so" which do not form dependent clauses.

"Therefore" however would not be considered a subordinating conjunction as its use results in the formation of independent clauses. But it is clearly different from conjunctions like "and" as it sounds marked when used without a preceding context. These types of words that necessarily link two clauses but do not form dependent clauses when doing so are sometimes referred to as conjunctive adjectives.

It's also important to note that clausal conjunctions can often evolve into discourse markers making them even more difficult to accurately and consistently categorize, as in the case of "so".